# Entity Framework Stored Procedures and POCO

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, entity, poco

I need advice on using stored procedures with Entity Framwork 4.x to return data into POCO objects.  I don't want to have to copy the data from an entity object to a POCO object.  I want to execute a stored proc and have the data loaded directly into my POCO class.

Is there a way to do this?  Do I need some sort of mapping like you would use in Nhibernate?  If so, could this mapping be attribute based?

Edit:  Using Justin's help below, I found that the way to do this is:

```
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@p1", "xxxx");
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@p2", "yyyy");

SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[2];
parameters[0] = p1;
parameters[1] = p2;

returned = base.ExecuteStoreQuery<YourClass>("exec your_stored_proc_name @p1, @p2", parameters);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the generic version of ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) once you [get to the ObjectContext](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/0c1f8425-55f4-4600-9605-a925220d5a25):

```
var listOfType= ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
                    .ExecuteStoreQuery<Type>("SPROCNAME");
```

[Here is the MSDN sample code (just change the TSQL to a sproc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx)

[And, here is one that shows how to deal with parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx)

The newer versions of EF has [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [DbContext.Database to get the ObjectContext easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
var listOfType = context.Database.SqlQuery<Type>("SPROCNAME");
```

Comment: @MystereMan Updated, sorry :)

Comment: This seems to at least require `SqlQuery<Type>("EXEC SPROCNAME")`. If your sproc has parameters you have to include them in your SQL statement as well.