# Entity Framework not getting column info on a different schema

Tags: entity-framework, schema

I am having trouble getting column information on a different schema.

It was working fine until we changed the connection string.

[image: Get Column Information]

default schema is [dbo]
the newly adding stored procedure is in "different_schema"

Does anyone know and had the same experience on this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I seem to remember needing to do something with FMTONLY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794671/why-do-we-have-to-write-set-fmtonly-off-in-stored-procedures-when-using-entity-f

Comment: Thank you. I read this before and thought this has something to do with the different schema but I was wrong.

Applying SET FMTONLY OFF; did the trick.

Comment: great I will add the answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of the stored proc temporarily add

SET FMTONLY OFF

to get the column information returned.

This is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794671/why-do-we-have-to-write-set-fmtonly-off-in-stored-procedures-when-using-entity-f)