# Stored Procedure returns int value rather than result set in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_GetAllLesiureActivitiesNew]
    (@ActivityLeaderID int = null)
as 
begin
    declare @TempLeisureActivites TABLE
        ([ActivityPlan_ID] [int]  NULL,
         [ActivityRecurrence_ID] [int] NULL,
         [ActivityName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
         [Activity] [nvarchar](max) NULL,   
         [IsResponse] [bit] NULL,
         [IsLOI] [bit] NULL,
         [clientcount] [int] NULL,  
         [Location] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
         [StartDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
         [EndDatetime] [datetime] NULL)

    insert into @TempLeisureActivites
        select distinct 
            ap.ActivityPlan_ID, ap.ActivityRecurrence_ID, 
            ap.ActivityName, orgla.Activity, orgla.IsResponse,
            orgla.IsLOI,
            (select count(distinct cc.ID ) from Client cc join Activity_Clients acc on cc.ID=acc.Client_ID join ActivityPlan app on acc.ActivityRecurrence_ID=app.ActivityRecurrence_ID where app.ActivityRecurrence_ID=ap.ActivityRecurrence_ID  and cc.Status=1) as clientcount,l.Location,ap.StartDateTime,ap.EndDatetime 
from ActivityPlan ap
left outer join Location l on ap.ActivityLocationID =l.ID left join Activity_Clients ac on ap.ActivityRecurrence_ID=ac.ActivityRecurrence_ID 
left outer join Client c on ac.Client_ID=c.ID
left outer join LeisureActivity orgla on ap.ActivityType=orgla.ID 
where ap.ActivityLeaderID in(0,@ActivityLeaderID) and c.[Status]=1

    if(@ActivityLeaderID is not null and @ActivityLeaderID>0)
    begin


declare @Activities nvarchar(max)
declare @Locations nvarchar(max)
declare @CISelection nvarchar(50)
declare @IsAllLocs bit

declare @TempRecurID int
declare @TempAPID int

--BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
--BEGIN TRY

 declare @RecurIDsCursor CURSOR
declare @RecurIDsRowsCount int

 --print 'Before cursor logic starts'
set @RecurIDsCursor=CURSOR STATIC FOR
select ActivityPlan_ID,ActivityRecurrence_ID from @TempLeisureActivites

OPEN @RecurIDsCursor
set @RecurIDsRowsCount=(SELECT @@CURSOR_ROWS)

--print 'cursor rows count:'+cast(@RecurIDsRowsCount as nvarchar)

FETCH NEXT
FROM @RecurIDsCursor INTO @TempAPID,@TempRecurID

WHILE @RecurIDsRowsCount>0
BEGIN

--select @Activities=NULL,@Locations=NULL
--print 'looping started...'
select @Activities='',@Locations=''

select @CISelection=NULL,@IsAllLocs=0

--print 'Activity Plan ID'+cast(@TempAPID as nvarchar)+',Recur ID:'+ cast(@TempRecurID as nvarchar)

select @CISelection=[CommonInterestsSelection] from [dbo].[ActivityPlan] where ActivityPlan_ID=@TempAPID and [ActivityRecurrence_ID]=@TempRecurID


--print 'CI Selection:'+@CISelection

if(@CISelection='Specific')
begin
select @Activities+=(
case when la.Activity is not null then 
 ISNULL(la.Activity,'')+',' end) from [dbo].[ActivityPlan_Filters] apf
left outer join [dbo].[LeisureActivity] la on la.ID=apf.FilterID 
where [ActivityRecurrence_ID]=@TempRecurID and apf.FilterType='Common_Interests'

if(LEN(@Activities)>0)
begin
select @Activities=LEFT(@Activities, LEN(@Activities) - 1)
end
end
else if(@CISelection='Top')
begin
select @Activities=[CommonInterestValue] from [dbo].[ActivityPlan] where ActivityPlan_ID=@TempAPID and [ActivityRecurrence_ID]=@TempRecurID
end
else if(@CISelection='NA')
begin
select @Activities='ALL'
end

--print 'Activities:'+@Activities
select @IsAllLocs=[IsAllLocations] from [dbo].[ActivityPlan] where ActivityPlan_ID=@TempAPID and [ActivityRecurrence_ID]=@TempRecurID
if(@IsAllLocs=1)
begin
select @Locations='ALL'
end
else if(@IsAllLocs=0)
begin
select @Locations+=(
case when loc.Location is not null then 
 ISNULL(loc.Location,'')+',' end) from [dbo].[ActivityPlan_Filters] apf
left outer join [dbo].[Location] loc on loc.ID=apf.FilterID 
where [ActivityRecurrence_ID]=@TempRecurID and apf.FilterType='Locations'

if(LEN(@Locations)>0)
begin
select @Locations=LEFT(@Locations, LEN(@Locations) - 1)
end
end

--print 'Locations:'+@Locations

--print 'before updation'
update @TempLeisureActivites
set Activity=@Activities,Location=@Locations
where ActivityPlan_ID=@TempAPID and ActivityRecurrence_ID=@TempRecurID

--print 'after updation'

FETCH NEXT
FROM @RecurIDsCursor INTO @TempAPID,@TempRecurID

SET @RecurIDsRowsCount=@RecurIDsRowsCount-1
END
CLOSE @RecurIDsCursor
DEALLOCATE @RecurIDsCursor


end
select * from @TempLeisureActivites
end
```

It returns Result set while executing in SQL Server Management Studio but in Asp.net MVC using Entity Framework it returns an integer instead of Result Set like below.

```
  public virtual int sp_GetAllLesiureActivitiesNew(Nullable<int> activityLeaderID)
        {
            var activityLeaderIDParameter = activityLeaderID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ActivityLeaderID", activityLeaderID) :
                new ObjectParameter("ActivityLeaderID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_GetAllLesiureActivitiesNew", activityLeaderIDParameter);
        }
```

I found one article but it does not help me([Stored procedure returns int instead of result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245567/stored-procedure-returns-int-instead-of-result-set)).
How Could i solve my problem?

Comment: A stored procedure's return value is an `INT` specifying the number of rows affected by an operation (like `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`). For a stored procedure which does not use any of those operations, the return value from the stored procedure is defined to be -1. To get the result set from a stored procedure, try using the `.ExecuteStoreQuery()` method instead of `ExecuteFunction`

Comment: @marc_s  Above Stored Procedure returns rows when executing in Sql Server management studio.It returns correct table result  in sql server.But in entity framework it returns integer  not result set.

Comment: Yes - I know - you said that - and I was trying to tell you to use **`ExecuteStoreQuery()`** instead of `ExecuteFunction` to be able to **get those rows** .....

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

The ExecuteFunction() Method returns the number of rows, which were affected as an integer.

If you want it to return `ObjectResult<YourEntityType>` instead.
Change it to:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<YourEntityType>("sp_GetAllLesiureActivitiesNew", activityLeaderIDParameter);
```

But I think that the better way of doing it is now:

```
Dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx)'s an Article that shows an example.

Comment: In DbContext.cs  it returns integer like below                                                                                     public virtual int sp_GetAllLesiureActivitiesNew(Nullable<int> activityLeaderID){}

Comment: You have to know the EntityType if you want it to return ObjectResult<T>. Look at my update! otherwise it will only return the number of affected rows as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the "**SQL Server Profiler**" tool, where you can track the SP and how the EF ran it, so you can see if the SP returns an error.

I wrote about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72162214/3374391