# MVC: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got an error while I try to get to my view. I've tried without IEnumerable but it doesn't work as well.

Error:
MVC: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Int32 while this dictionary requires a type model element System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Cinema.Models.Video].

```
@model IEnumerable<Cinema.Models.Video>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

My controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        CinemaEntities db = new CinemaEntities();
        return View(db.SearchVideo(""));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string VideoName)
    {
        CinemaEntities db = new CinemaEntities();
        return View(db.SearchVideo(VideoName));
    }
}
```

My SearchVideo

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Video_SearchVideo_Result1> Video_SearchVideo(string videoName)
{
    var videoNameParameter = videoName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("VideoName", videoName) :
        new ObjectParameter("VideoName", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Video_SearchVideo_Result1>("Video_SearchVideo", videoNameParameter);
}

public virtual int SearchVideo(string videoName)
{
    var videoNameParameter = videoName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("VideoName", videoName) :
        new ObjectParameter("VideoName", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SearchVideo", videoNameParameter);
}
```

Comment: Please show update the question with the ECinema.Models.Video model

Comment: `int SearchVideo` is being passed to a view `return View(db.SearchVideo(VideoName))` that expects `@model IEnumerable<ECinema.Models.Video>` just as the error message states. You need to match up what you return to the with what it (the view) expects to receive

Comment: but I've got that @model IEnumerable<ECinema.Models.Video> in my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchVideo` returns an `int` as per your code:

```
public virtual int SearchVideo(string videoName)
```

You need to change that function to return `IEnumerable<ECinema.Models.Video>` instead.

*The easiest way is likely to use LINQ rather than call the stored procedure. But if you **really** want to keep the stored procedure, you may be able to configure it to return your [desired type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34151229/34092).*

Comment: It works after while, thx