# Quick CRUD access for simple SQL schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, data-access

I'm a little behind the times on data access and need to be pointed in the right direction. I currently have just a single SQL Server db table with about 35 columns in it. I'm building a WCF web service to provide access to it and am trying to figure out the quickest way to link up the C# based web service to the database.

I've been looking at Entity Framework but it seems pretty heavy and everything I've found on it so far seems to assume you already know something about it so I didn't want to get too far into it if it's the wrong path. I'm not fully sold on the idea of generating SQL in the application. I already have a DataContract class with properties for each column in the table, I'm just looking for an automatic way to map columns to properties and properties back to columns/sproc parameters. I already wrote some code that uses reflection to map data from a different source to this DataContract (matching on property name with a dictionary of additional mappings as a backup) so it's not that much work to do the same here, but I wanted to see what else is available. What I want to avoid is writing out each `PropertyName = ColumnName.Value`. Is there something light weight built into VS2010 .NET 4.0 for a simple case like this? Would directly calling a stored procedure through EF as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930408/entity-framework-stored-procedures-and-poco) be a good option? It looks a little out of date.

Comment: You might want to have a look at  [NHiberante](http://nhibernate.info/)

Comment: IMHO the educational burden for Entity Framework and NHibernate is approximately the same.

Comment: @DavidTansey Well that's not a good sign. I can't find anything (that works) about mapping a stored procedure to an existing POCO. Any time I've looked at Entity Framework there has always been a quicker solution available, which is why I'm still unfamiliar with it. I'm very surprised that it's this difficult to find how to map db columns to an existing class with it given it's an _ORM tool_. I could have already coded it myself in the time I've spent trying to figure out how to use EF. So at this point I will, but still interested to see if there is a better answer that I just can't find.

Comment: Take the time to look at the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx which is a short tutorial for automatically reverse engineering an existing database into a 'code first' model for Entity Framework.  Be sure to check the prerequisites, especially `Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio`.  Then you can jump to step 3 because you already have a database.  When you finish step 3 you should have a POCO class for your table and your stored proc should also be callable from the EF context -- you can decide which to use.  This one is pretty short and sweet - good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Dapper, a "micro-ORM". It's used by SO. I've used it beautifully as "an automatic way to map columns to properties" and it appears to also do "properties back to columns/sproc parameters" but I haven't used it for that. It's superb - I had it going in about 5 minutes after getting it with Nuget.  I'm a newbie to EF and wouldn't recommend it without a guide.

```
    IEnumerable<TModel> result;
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_mysqlConnString))
    {
        // "Query" is a Dapper extension method that stuffs the datareader into objects based on the column names
        result = conn.Query<TModel>("Select * from YourTable");
    }
    // do stuff with result
```

This links to a full example, instead of just the piece I pulled out of my current project. http://www.tritac.com/bp-24-dapper-net-by-example

other Dapper information: c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/… and liangwu.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/dapper-net-samples talk about it.

(moved from comment as this was more an answer than a comment - I'm trying to do the proper task in the proper place).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with EntityFramework before getting your answer, but it sounds like a good option. EF 5 or above may have been a good option, but 4.4 did not end up being spectacular. One problem I had was I couldn't delete all records from the table (through ExecuteSqlCommand) and then save records to the table in a single database transaction. It only supports TransactionScope which is a pretty crappy solution when only a single SQL transaction is actually needed. Mapping a sproc to an existing POCO was possible in 4.4, but was clunky and I ended up just using entites